# How to use SELECT query with many variables in psycopg2

Tags: python, database, postgresql, select, psycopg2

I am trying to query my PostgreSQL table using psycopg2. I need to use 3 variables in the query because they will change from execution to execution. This is the code I have used:

```
def select_from_table(values, dbname, host, user, password, month,cluster,date):
    try:
        tup = open_connection_to_db(dbname, host, user, password)
        sql_command = """SELECT listing_id, price_x FROM test WHERE month = %s AND cluster = %s AND date = %s;"""
        tup[1].execute(sql_command, (month,cluster,date,))
        tup[0].commit()
        print("Selecting rows from mobile table using cursor.fetchall")   
        df = pd.read_sql(sql_command, tup[0])
        return df
    except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
        print("Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL", error)
    finally:
        tup[0].close()
        tup[1].close()
        print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")
```

You can presume that the open_connection_to_db function is working (I have used it so far) and it returns 2 variables:
tup[0] = connection
tup[1] = cursor

I am getting this error:

```
Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL Execution failed on sql 'SELECT listing_id, price_x FROM test WHERE month = %s AND cluster = %s AND date = %s': syntax error at or near "%"
LINE 1: ...ELECT listing_id, price_x FROM test WHERE month = %s AND clu...
                                                             ^
```

Comment: Try: `tup[1].execute(sql_command, (month,cluster,date))`; notice there's no comma after `date`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass formatted string to execute function ie you need something like this

```
sql_command = """SELECT listing_id, price_x FROM test 
WHERE month = %s AND cluster = %s AND date = %s;""" % (month,cluster,date)
tup[1].execute(sql_command)
```